# Ninject: bind interface to multiple implementations

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject

I have an interface called `IXMLModelsRepository`, and i have a concrete implementation called `XMLModelsRepository` which simply reads from an XML file.

However, i want to improve the function, and i want to temporary cache the elements into a `Dictionary<>` list.

I don't want to modify the existing `XMLModelsRepository`, but i want to create a new class that adds the caching functionality on top.

How can i bind using `Ninject` an interface to two concrete implementations?

```
// the interface i am working with
public interface IXMLModelsRepository
{
    Product GetProduct(Guid entity_Id);
}

// concrete implementation that reads from XML document
public class XMLModelsRepository : IXMLModelsRepository
{
    private readonly XDocument _xDoc = LoadXMLDocument();

    public Product GetProduct(Guid entity_Id)
    {
        return _xDoc.Element("root").Elements("Product").Where(p => p.Attribute("Entity_Id").Value == entity_Id.ToString();
    }
}

// concrete implementation that is only responsable of caching the results
//    this is the class that i will use in the project,
//    but it needs a parameter of the same interface type
public class CachedXMLModelsRepository : IXMLModelsRepository
{
    private readonly IXMLModelsRepository _repository;
    public CachedXMLModelsRepository(
        IXMLModelsRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, Product> cachedProducts = new Dictionary<Guid, Product>();
    public Product GetProduct(Guid entity_Id)
    {
        if (cachedProducts.ContainsKey(entity_Id))
        {
            return cachedProducts[entity_Id];
        }

        Product product = _repository.GetProduct(entity_Id);
        cachedProducts.Add(entity_Id, product);

        return product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you call it `IXMLModelsRepository` (with XML). Isn't XML an implementation detail that the consumer of this interface shouldn't care about?

Comment: Good point. The models always comes from an xml file, and i named them XML Models, because i also have Business Models which are the database models.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `WhenInjectedExactlyInto` construct.

```
kernel.Bind<IXMLModelsRepository >().To<CachedXMLModelsRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IXMLModelsRepository >().To<XMLModelsRepository>()
    .WhenInjectedExactlyInto(typeof(CachedXMLModelsRepository));
```

In the above example Ninject would use the cached instance for all lookups of the interface, but when constructing the cached repository, it would inject the non-cached object.